# Trying to use std::vector<MyClass>

Tags: c++, object, vector, sdl

I’m having problem with using vectors of my own class. My intension is to create a new object on every spacebar click.  I've already written some code:

classes.h

```
class someClass
{
public:
    short x;
    short y;
    someClass::someClass();
};
```

classes.cpp

```
someClass::someClass()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
using namepsace std;    
vector<someClass> vMyVector;
(...)
case SDLK_SPACE:
    vMyVector.push_back();
break;
```

I also tried put that extra line in case SDLK_SPACE:

```
someClass *temp = new someClass(); 
vMyVector.push_back(temp);
```

But in both situations compiler return errors like

> error C3867: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back': function call missing
>   argument list; use '&std::vector<_Ty>::push_back' to create a pointer
>   to member with [_Ty=someClass]

I've already spend about an hour on searching some books and reading various topics on the Internet, but none of them were useful. I put my hope in you guys!

Comment: You were all right, writing

someClass temp; 
vMyVector.push_back(temp);

was the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared the vector containing objects of someClass but tried to add a pointer.

Write instead

```
someClass *temp = new someClass(); 
vMyVector.push_back(*temp);
```

or

```
someClass temp; 
vMyVector.push_back(temp);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! :)

Answer (score 4):

In the first case you're missing an argument to `push_back`,. It should be an instance of `SomeClass`, *not a pointer* to SomeClass, which, incidently, is the problem in the second 
case.

**EDIT:**
If you just want to add an element, constructed with the default constructor, you can just do

```
v.resize (v.size () + 1)
```

and refer t the new object with

```
v.back ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your definition of vMyVector:

```
vector<someClass> vMyVector;
```

you are not supposed to be pushing *pointers* to it, rather full objects:

```
 someClass *temp = new someClass(); 
 vMyVector.push_back(*temp);
 delete temp;
```

Notice the *, which will *dereference* your pointer and give an object of type `someClass`. Also, thanks to sehe's comment about the need to delete the pointer after you push the object on to the array, since you are making a copy of the object and the pointer would be left dangling. Of course, if you really need to delete there, depends on how you are using the pointer in the rest of the function, but at some point you will need to delete it.

Actually, you don't need to use new/delete at all (but I started from your code to show where your problem resides). You simply do:

```
 someClass temp; 
 vMyVector.push_back(temp);
```

Comment: OMG - that leads to nice memory leaks! You are dynamically allocating, only to store a _copy_ of that in the vector, and forever forgetting to delete the temp.

Comment: still -1 for completely senseless use of `new`

Comment: Wouldn't this cause quite the memory leak since `push_back()` makes a copy of the object you pass in and then you would have one instance on the heap you just created and the object copy constructed from it in the vector.

Comment: @r_ahlskog: actually no, because the storage for the copy is managed by the `std::vector` (it would possibly create heap-fragmentation but I'd defer that to the profiling stage)

Comment: @sergio slightly better; even better `vMyVector.push_back(someClass());` or `vMyVector.push_back(std::move(temp));` or simply even `vMyVector.resize(vMyVector.size()+1);`

Comment: @sehe, I see he changed the answer to delete the heap allocated object while I wrote my comment apparently, so +1 to your comment on senseless new

Answer (score 1):

You have vector of objects, then you first try to push_back nothing at all and then you try to push_back pointer to your object, not the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `vector<T>`, then you need to supply a `T` (or a `T &`) when you call `push_back()`. In your first code snippet, you're not supplying anything at all.  In your second code snippet, you're pushing a `T *`, not a `T`.

Try something like this:

```
someClass temp;
...
vMyVector.push_back(temp);
```